# Reaction of succinic acid with ammonia

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

When succinic acid is treated with excess $\ce{NH3}$, what will the mechanism be? I feel both $\ce{COOH}$ groups should be converted to $\ce{CONH2}$, but this is not the product.

Comment: Did you actually mean to say $\ce{COONH2}$? Because that is about as wrong as it gets …

Comment: I actually think you mean $\ce{CONH2}$, the amide, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yup.. Its amide

Comment: @Jan It's not as simple as it seems... [the ring actually closes](https://thosci.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/esno.png). (Picture taken from [here](https://www.thosci.com/synthesis-of-suiccinimide/))

Comment: @DHMO I knew. But OP suggested a peroxide product which was just badly wrong ;) (Actually, it *is* as simple as it seems because five-membered rings are kinetically favoured and intramolecular attacks are faster than intermolecular ones, etc. etc.)

Comment: @Jan there's another problem: we don't need to make the acyl chloride before making the amide?

Comment: @DHMO No, amides are the ‘thermodynamic hole’, they will be formed from acid + $\ce{NH3}$ given enough time. All conditions out there are just to accelerate. It works better, if you start at an ester though.

Comment: There are no conditions given! In which case, why not ammonium bis-succinate?

Answer (score 5):

From [Synthesis of Succinimide on Thomas' Chemistry](https://www.thosci.com/synthesis-of-suiccinimide/):

> Add 186 g of succinic acid to RBF, place the beaker in an ice bath and start adding 220 ml of 26% ammonia slowly. Assemble short path distillation without a condenser, add some boiling chips. Heat the mixture under a small flame to distil of all the water. When the temperature reaches over 100°C the mixture darkens. Switch the receiver and collect everything that comes off before yellow fumes temp 280-300°C. Cool down to room temperature and place the receiver into a freezer for 24h, recrystallize the crude succinimide in hot ethanol. Then filter the crystals and wash with 40 ml of cold ethanol.

(Note that RBF = round-bottom flask)

[image: mechanism]

The catch is that the amide can attack itself to close the ring, forming succinimide.

There are two rounds of amidification via a nucleophilic addition/elimination mechanism.